# Rails: how to automatically create models from an sql file

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have an sql file with respective `create table` statements (and columns, keys etc.). Is there a way to automatically generate models (if not even scaffolds) from this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Rails doesn't have anything out of the box that will do this for you. You could always write a custom generator to parse the sql file and create models. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually use sql file create database.

Simple way is use `sqlite`, it's easier to setup.

`cat db.sql | sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3`

Then run `rake db:schema:dump` to dump database to schema in Rails.

Comment: Thanks! I used Postgresql instead. Then I applied @MZaragoza's suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the [schema_to_scaffold gem](https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold)

> This Gem generates Rails command strings based on a Rails database
>   schema you already have. Unlike traditional migrations, which modify
>   the database as they generate Rails scaffolding code, this Gem reads
>   the schema for your database and generates the Rails code which
>   matches your database's existing columns.

Comment: Thanks but I need to create the Rails schema first, I just have an SQL file for now... or is there a way to translate my SQL file into a Rails schema?

Comment: @bananaappletw's suggestion solved the main problem, then I applied your solution as next step ;)